# Trying to simulate sand pixels using raycasts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to simulate sand particles with a prefab gameobject, there's a script inside it that checks if the ground raycast has a collision detection, and if it has, it moves either to the left or to the right. It half works but the sand gameobjects stack in 5-6 blocks horizontally, here's my script:

ps: I know alot of raycasts uses alot of performance, but i'll do this way for now, when I learn more about this, i'll use unity tiles. I'm also using a simple OnMouseButtonDown to spawn the sand gameobjects into the scene, each sand gameobject has a collider so the raycasts can work properly. *sorry if there's any english mistake*

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class sandSimulation : MonoBehaviour
{
    int speedY = 1;
    int speedX = 1;
    [SerializeField] Transform ground, corner1, corner2, side1, side2;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask layer, solid;
    //public Rigidbody2D rb;
    bool goingDown;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // rb.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3(0,-speedY,0) * 1);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, ground.position, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, corner1.position, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, corner2.position, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawLine(side1.position, side2.position, Color.red);

        RaycastHit2D hitSolidDown = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, ground.position, solid);
        RaycastHit2D hitGround = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, ground.position, layer);
        RaycastHit2D hitCorner1 = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, corner2.position, layer);
        RaycastHit2D hitCorner2 = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, corner1.position, layer);
        RaycastHit2D hitSide1 = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, corner1.position, layer);
        RaycastHit2D hitSide2 = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, corner2.position, layer);

        if (hitSolidDown.collider == null)
        {
            if(transform.position != transform.position)
            {
                goingDown = true;
            }
            if (hitGround.collider == null)
            {
                //rb.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3(0, -speedY, 0) * 1);
                transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, -speedY));
                goingDown = true;
            }
            else if(hitGround.collider != null)
            {
                goingDown = false;
            }

            if (!goingDown)
            {
                if (hitCorner1.collider == null)
                {
                    //rb.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3(-speedX, 0, 0) * 1);
                    transform.Translate(new Vector2(-speedX, 0));
                    Debug.Log("Moved");
                }
                else if (hitCorner2.collider == null)
                {
                    //rb.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3(speedX, 0, 0) * 1);
                    transform.Translate(new Vector2(speedX, 0));
                    Debug.Log("Moved");
                }

                if(hitCorner1.collider != null && hitGround.collider != null && hitSide1.collider == null)
                {
                    transform.Translate(new Vector2(speedX, -speedY));
                }
                if (hitCorner2.collider != null && hitGround.collider != null && hitSide2.collider == null)
                {
                    transform.Translate(new Vector2(-speedX, -speedY));
                }
            }
            if(hitCorner1.collider != null || hitCorner2.collider != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("bug?");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bknvJ.png)

[Here is a gif showing whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTI0N.gif)
I got it working better and updated my code a little, but sometimes the sand drops just enters eachother and they still have a chance to stack.

Comment: What is your question/problem ? You should provide visuals with this kind of simulation.

Comment: I'm sorry Oktomus, I was going to add an screenshot but then forgot.